# Displaying multiple json arrays with ajax/javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I'm having some issues displaying multiple JSON arrays if anybody could help, 
i would appreciate it.

JSON

```
{ 
"houseOne": [
    {
        "name": "John Clarke",
        "age": 22,
        "dob": "19-11-90" 
    },
      {
        "name": "Mitch Woodier",
        "age": 20,
        "dob": "23-10-92"  
    },
      {
        "name": "Mavis Waddingham",
        "age": 21,
        "dob": "10-11-91"  
    }
],

          "houseTwo": [
    {
        "name": "Luke Woodier",
        "age": 22,
        "dob": "19-11-90" 
    },
      {
        "name": "Rob Clarke",
        "age": 20,
        "dob": "23-10-92"  
    },
      {
        "name": "Alex Gayfag",
        "age": 21,
        "dob": "10-11-91"  
    }
]
```

}

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ajaxRequest(url)
    {
       var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

            // Work around for IE caching problem
            if (url.indexOf('?') < 0) {
                today = new Date();
                url += '?' + today.getTime();
            }

        request.open("GET", url, false);
        request.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        request.send();
        return request.responseText;
    }

    var data = ajaxRequest("results.json");
    var houses = JSON.parse(data);

    function displayJson() {
        var myDiv =document.getElementById("content");
        for (house = 0; house < 3; house++) {
            var home = houses.houseOne[house];
            myDiv.innerHTML += houseDetails(home,house);

         }
    } 


    function houseDetails(home,houseNumber){


    var myHTML = "<h1>House Mate "+ (houseNumber +1)+"</h1>";
    myHTML += "<table>";
    myHTML += "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>D.O.B</th></tr>";
    myHTML += "<tr>";
    myHTML += "<td>";
    myHTML += home.name;
    myHTML += "</td>";
    myHTML += "<td>";
    myHTML += home.age;
    myHTML += "</td>";
    myHTML += "<td>";
    myHTML += home.dob;
    myHTML += "</td>";
    myHTML += "</table>";

    return myHTML



    }      

</script>
```

Basically I can get it to display houseOne as a table but I can't get it to display both houseOne and houseTwo, I hope this is clear I'm not very good with web dev.

Regards,

Dean

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend not using synchronous ajax request, it would be better to use a callback.
You could itterate through every house object like so:

```
function displayJson() {
    var i,h,ret=[];
    var myDiv =document.getElementById("content");
    // houseone and housetwo
    for (h in houses) {
        // houseone and housetwo are arrays: [house,house,house]
        // for every house in this array do:
        for(i=0;i<houses[h].length;i++){
          var home = houses[h][i];
          ret.push(houseDetails(home,i));
        }
     }
     //setting innerHTML is resource intensive
     // no reason to do this within a loop.
     myDiv.innerHTML=ret.join("");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it been pulling my hair out all day trying to work this out. Web development defiantly isn't for me.

Comment: It's a slow and frustrating journey, but it can be rewarding when it all starts to slot into place. Stick with it.

Comment: Patience might be one of the best qualities of a developer. I have been screaming at my computer some times but then realize that computers don't make mistakes; people do.

Answer (score 3):

In your displayJson() function you're only referencing `house.houseOne`

```
var home = houses.houseOne[house];
```

Here's an updated version (I've added jQuery too) http://jsfiddle.net/XzZUR/1/

JSON

```
var houses = {
    "houseOne": [{
        "name": "John Clarke",
            "age": 22,
            "dob": "19-11-90"
    }, {
        "name": "Mitch Woodier",
            "age": 20,
            "dob": "23-10-92"
    }, {
        "name": "Mavis Waddingham",
            "age": 21,
            "dob": "10-11-91"
    }],

        "houseTwo": [{
        "name": "Luke Woodier",
            "age": 22,
            "dob": "19-11-90"
    }, {
        "name": "Rob Clarke",
            "age": 20,
            "dob": "23-10-92"
    }, {
        "name": "Alex Gayfag",
            "age": 21,
            "dob": "10-11-91"
    }]
};
```

Javascript

```
function displayJson() {
    var myDiv = $("#content");

    $.each(houses, function(){
        var house = this;
        $(house).each(function(key){
            myDiv.append(houseDetails(this,key));
        })
    });

}
```

Comment: I don't really see why you would involve jQuery to iterate through object and array. You can iterate through an object with for(key in object){item=object[key]} You can do the same for arrays but it's inefficient, better to do for(counter=0;counter<array.length;counter++){item=array[counter]}

Comment: Because it has a succinct function for doing so and by including jQuery, I'm also simultaneously hinting that there's a more convenient way of manipulating the DOM.

Comment: myDiv.innerHTML is undefined because myDiv is a jQuery object; not a DOM element.

Comment: Whoops, thanks for pointing out. I'd left the old code underneath by accident. Fixed now.

Comment: +1, But it would be slightly better to leave the html manipulation outside the loop. Fill an array with the html value and set the Element's innerHTML when the loop is done would be quicker. I agree jQuery can be handy for DOM manipulation and making you ajax calls

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys, I really appreciate it.